# How to display menu items on image click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview, menuitem

I have created action bar which has one image aligned at the right corner.I want to add some menu item which should be displayed when user clicks on that.It is like spinner.

Can someone please help me with the steps or code.

Activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/red">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/pic13" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="User Profile"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#456789"
            android:popupBackground="@color/title"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Menu/item.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="@string/gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

</menu>
```

Activity:

```
 package com.example.vimal.edkul;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class UserAccordion extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you might be missing some ClickListeners that listens to the user clicks on your button.

I reference these code from [javacodegeeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/)

**AndroidToolbarExample.java**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.androidtoolbarexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidToolbarExample extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initToolBar();

}

public void initToolBar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.toolbarTitle);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar_arrow);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ****** HERE *******
                    //implement your click stuff here
                    switch(v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.selectItems:
                          ....
                        break;

                    }

                }
            }

    );
  }
}
```